# Jenkins is deleting workspaces on agents

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins is deleting workspaces on agents/nodes after 30 days or 30th day of month. After looking into jenkins folder located at

```
/var/lib/jenkins/logs/tasks
```

I found logs here with name `Workspace\ clean-up.log`. Why this is being created? I suspected it may be because of [workspace cleanup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin). Now I have deleted this plugin as well, but this issue is not resolved. How to know why workspaces are getting deleted on agents? Is there a way i can stop this?

Comment: That's not a programming question but one about the use of a particular piece of software. It's not even a good question, because lots of info is missing (read [ask]).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, your remark "not a programming question" could generally be applied to most of the [Jenkins] questions. Do you believe there is a better place to post these? ServerFault has 527 tags, DevOps Beta has 432, SuperUser has 337, Unix&Linux has 88,  AskUnbuntu has 43. Meanwhile, S/O has 38000+. If you want a [Jenkins] answer, seems like this is the place to get one. Maybe it's 'cos Hudson/Jenkins predates all the other sites. If they best belong elsewhere, should that be a meta question to migrate all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to [Jenkins Features Controlled with System Properties](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/system-properties/)

- **hudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.disabled**
  [ false ]
  Don't clean up old workspaces on agent nodes
- **hudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.recurrencePeriodHours**
  [ 24 ]
  How often workspace cleanup should run, in hours.
- **hudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.retainForDays**
  [ 30 ]
  Unused workspaces are retained for this many days before qualifying for deletion

If you have more than one node and jobs can float across nodes, you really want them cleaned up.

The order of parameters in the startup command is important, but basically these options belong at the end.

Refer to:  [RPM launcher](https://github.com/jenkinsci/packaging/blob/master/rpm/build/SOURCES/jenkins.init.in) or [Docker launcher](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/jenkins.sh)

It becomes:
`$JENKINS_JAVA_CMD $JENKINS_JAVA_OPTIONS -DJENKINS_HOME=$JENKINS_HOME -jar $JENKINS_WAR $JENKINS_PARAMS`

UPDATE: As of [LTS 222.1(ref. to Changelog notes)](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.222/), Jenkins introduced a **global build discarder** default. It's worth reading [Cloudbee's - Best Strategy for Disk Space Management: Clean Up Old Builds](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/215549798-Best-Strategy-for-Disk-Space-Management-Clean-Up-Old-Builds)

Comment: +1 very useful. Would have saved me a lot of time spent on custom cleanup solutions, if I had known about it.

Comment: How to define System Property in Jenkins in ubuntu machine. Currently i have defined it in /etc/default/jenkins as follow. 
JAVA_ARGS="-Dhudson.model.WorkspaceCleanupThread.disabled=true"
Do you think it is right way?

Comment: Updated explanation. There are JAVA_OPTIONS and JENKINS_PARAMS. You want JENKINS_PARAMS. Reefer to the examples.

Comment: @IanW, Since this behavior initiated after 30 days I am waiting to verify it. Once done I will update the question.

Comment: @IanW, It works well, workspaces  are not getting deleted now. I have marked the question as answered.

Comment: @IanW  "If you have more than one node and jobs can float across nodes, you really want them cleaned up." ----

Why? If it destroys your pipeline (which it does), I'd rather let them stay forever...

Comment: @Rop, I guess it depends on your specific infrastructure and circumstances. With 10000+ jobs and a pool of 50+ nodes, it's massive waste of space for us to keep all workspaces everywhere in the event a job rolls back onto a given node. Evidently the Jenkins architect vision aligns w/my use case and that's why the option is enabled by default.